# AWS CDK Java - File Upload to S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, deployment, aws-cdk

I am using the AWS CDK (Java) to upload my lambdas to S3 with the below code.  I don't want the CDK to unpack my jar files.  This seems to be the only way to achieve this (it does work) but it uses deprecated code on the AssetOptions.builder().exclude().  Is there a better way of doing this in Java without using deprecated code?

```
List<ISource> lambdaSources = new ArrayList<>();
for(String lambda: lambdas) {   
    AssetOptions assetOptions = AssetOptions.builder().exclude(
        Arrays.asList("**", "!" + lambda + "-" + VERSION + SUFFIX)).build();
    lambdaSources.add(Source.asset("../" + lambda + "/build/libs/", assetOptions));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I might have found a better way of doing this which combines code upload with lambda creation. I am still interested in thoughts from experts in the CDK if there is a better approach.

BTW "lambda" is just an entity I created to hold relevant attributes of the various functions I have.

```
Function.Builder fnBuilder = Function.Builder.create(this, "Builder"); 
 fnBuilder.code(lambda.getCode())
    .functionName(lambda.getName())
    .handler(lambda.getHandler())
    .memorySize(lambda.getSize())
    .role(lambda.constructRole(this))
    .runtime(LambdaDetails.RUNTIME)
    .timeout(lambda.duration())
    .securityGroups(Arrays.asList(lambda.constructSecurityGroup(this)))
    .vpcSubnets(lambda.constructSubnets(this))
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not on the CDK team or a CDK expert, and I don't have specific Java code to offer. However, I found additional context about the deprecation warning while using the TypeScript CDK that may be helpful.

TLDR: I'm choosing to ignore the deprecation. Here's why:

The AWS CDK source is written in TypeScript, and [jsii](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/how-the-jsii-open-source-framework-meets-developers-where-they-are/) is used to generate the AWS CDK Construct libraries for other supported languages (Java, .NET, Python, etc.). What I describe below should still be relevant to the CDK for Java.

I agree that avoiding deprecated code is a good practice, in general. But that specific deprecation warning appears to be at least partly the misleading result of some CDK refactoring (see below). I call it 'misleading', because it caused some devs like me to (mis)interpret it to mean that `exclude` will no longer be supported in the future. Since no clear alternative was offered, it was very concerning.

However, after reading through more of the github repo, the `exclude` functionality looks like it'll remain available and supported, although the exact syntax may change.

After reading aws-cdk source code, pull requests [7708](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/7708) and [12700 (from only 10 days ago)](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/pull/12700), along with related issues [9447](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9447) and [10125](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/10125), it looks like `exclude` isn't really deprecated from a practical standpoint. Some comments call out the misunderstanding directly. In the TypeScript source, `exclude` is moving from `AssetOptions` in the `assets` module (where it is a deprecated property) to `CopyOptions` (via `FileOptions`) in the `core` module (where it is not deprecated).

Here's a key point: since `assets.AssetOptions` inherits from `core.CopyOptions` -- which in turn inherits from `copy.FileOptions` -- `exclude` remains effectively in place on the `AssetOptions` interface...at least for CDK V1!

For V2, some say they want to deprecate the entire assets module beyond just moving some shared types to core. I couldn't find a definitive reference on final V2 changes, but I'm interpreting the spirit of what I did find to mean that I can safely continue using glob patterns with `exclude` to customize S3 deployments. If the assets module does go away in V2, I expect the required code updates be minor - maybe even as simple as an import and/or type name change or two (YMMV of course).

Comment: Thanks for the insights.  I found a better solution but this might prove useful going forward.